# Can't login to careers.stackoverflow.com using claimid

Tags: support, jobs, login

Recently got an invite for Careers.stackoverflow.com but I can't seem to login. I get to the login screen for claimid and enter my correct username and password but when I hit submit the page simply refreshes and I'm staring at blank username and password fields. I logged out from SO and logged back in using claimid to determine if there was an issue there but it worked fine.

Any ideas/recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I figured it out. There's a field for entering just your username if you select your OpenID service. It autopopulates another field and formats the URL like this:

http://openid.claimid.com/my_username

Apparently I registered as this

http://claimid.com/my_username

Didn't realize that would be an issue. Sorry to bother.

Comment: you can pick your own answer as the answer to the question